# How to add "Disable User" admin-feature in Java EE application?

Tags: java, authentication, jakarta-ee, jaas, jdbcrealm

I have a Java EE application that uses `JDBCReal` as `JAAS Context` for authentication on GlassFish 3.1. And below is the authentication code in a JSF2.0 managedbean -

```java
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
try {
    if (request.getUserPrincipal() != null) {
        request.logout();
    }
    if (request.getUserPrincipal() == null) {
        request.login(this.username, this.password);
    }
```

I am trying to add some admin functionalities (like create/delete/update/disable user). I am almost done with all of them except for the "disable" one, which is confusing me on how to proceed.

The only way that I can think of right now is to add a field, something like "status", in the "users" table, which will have a value ("enabled" or "disabled"). And check that "status" before doing the authentication.

Is that how I should do it considering that I am using JAAS (JDBCRealm)? Or, is there some other (standard) way?

I am trying to see, if there is someone here who has some experience in this area and can point me towards the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you manage your users table through JDBC/JPA.

In unix/linux the `passwd -l` change the hash to an invalid value. From [`man passwd`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?passwd):

```
 -l   This option is used to lock the specified account and it is
      available to root only. The locking is performed by rendering
      the encrypted password into an invalid string (by prefixing the
      encrypted string with an !).
```

In practice an unlocked account from `/etc/shadow`:

```
test:$6$c7Lz2A2l$8AoSBy8C2U7uUns4aDRP2J/QRzUOYF...o69XPR/:15259:0:99999:7:::
```

And the same account after `passwd -l test`:

```
test:!$6$c7Lz2A2l$8AoSBy8C2U7uUns4aDRP2J/QRzUOYF...o69XPR/:15259:0:99999:7:::
```

The prefixed value is invalid because hash functions always return the same number of bits. If your stored value is longer than that length they will never match. You can do the same with your hashed passwords - just prefix the password with an `!` (or any other string) through JDBC/JPA.

Of course this does not work with plaintext passwords.

Another solution is removing the user's roles from the database. In this case the user could login but if you set up the `security-constraint`s well in the `web.xml` the user wouldn't be able to do anything (except logout).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. +1 for with your idea I don't have add to one more column "status" to the users table. But basically what I am trying to see is if it is necessary to manually check if the user exists and if yes is it disabled or enabled and then only do the login if the user exists and is enabled.

Comment: It's not necessary to check it manually, the `login()` method/JDBCRealm do it for you. But if you   want to print a more detailed error message ("login failed, disabled user", not just "login failed") you have to check it manually with JDBC/JPA. (Check the answer update too.)

Comment: Just needed somebody to confirm that. Thank you. I will accept your answer.